# question about distance between linearly independent vectors.

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I have two vectors **u** and **v** in $R^4$

let's say u = <4,-8,0,-2> and v =<4,0,-1,-3>

I know the distance between them is just $||u-v||$

then what is the distance from u to subspace span{v}?

I got a little stuck on this.

am I suppose to find the projection of **u** on **v** in this case?

If possible, please give an example.

Comment: find that projection and subtract it from $u$. Make a picture in the plane, take something simple, like distance of $<2,4>$ to the $x$-axis, which is span of $v=<-3,0>$

Answer (score 1):

With the use of projection distance   $d= \Vert(1-\frac{vv^T}{\Vert{v}\Vert^2})u\Vert$.
The formula is independent of dimensions ( $ n>1$)